# Search for URL Pattern and replace it on MySql using REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to search for all the URLs starting with `https://institute-of-coaching.com/......./?id=...&amp;utm_source=...&amp;utm_campaign=....&amp;utm_medium=....` from a series of data tables which contains this pattern under HTML tags

```
<a href=""institute-of-coaching.com/sf-webinar-sfw-5d-bha-dg/?id=sjn7962lmk&amp;utm_source=Coaching-Skills-Article-Banner&amp;utm_medium=Coaching-Skills-Article&amp;utm_campaign=Coaching-Skills-Blog"" target=""_blank"" rel=""noopener noreferrer""><img class=""aligncenter"" src=""....../banner-3.png"" alt=""coaching skills 17"" width=""618"" height=""234""></a>"
```

I have tried with this on MYSQL to search but it didn't work:

```
select * 
from ch_posts 
where post_content RLIKE '(institute-of-coaching\.com\/sf-webinar-sfw-5d-bha-dg\/?)\w*(=).([A-Za-z0-9])\w*([&][a-z]).*(target=)';
```

Can anyone help me debug this and achieve my goal to search and replace the URLs with URLs having no UTM Parameters on them.

Comment: What version of MySQL? You need 8.x to use `REPLACE_REGEXP()`.

Comment: You don't need to escape forward slash in regexp.

Comment: Why do you have two doublequotes around all the HTML attributes?

Comment: You need to escape `?` in the regexp.

Comment: I have two blockquotes around all the html parameters because of the software that I use. I usd this but still didn't get the appropriate result: select * from ch_posts where post_content RLIKE '(institute-of-coaching\.com/sf-webinar-sfw-5d-bha-dg/\?)\w*(=).([A-Za-z0-9])\w*([&][a-z]).*(target=)';